# Checks that jquery selectors are used in an efficient way

Tags: jquery, pycharm

Указанное в заголовке предупреждение выдается на вот этой строке:

```
$('#search input[name="q"]').autocomplete({
```

Как использовать селектор более эффективно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('#search').find('input[name="q"]').autocomplete({
```

Comment: А почему это более эффективно?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/ Так немного быстрее. На данном примере разница конечно незаметная, но стоит сразу писать эффективно.

Comment: @Romchik, разница получилась заметной. Быстрее работает гораздо.